# Posting JSON array via AJAX to php failed

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want to send JSON array via ajax call to a web service PHP. I've tried a lot of solution (most of the suggested similar answers for such question) with no clue.

My JSON array structure is:

```
var res= [{"id":-9007199254740990,
"NW":{"x":3.97,"y":5.83},
"SE":{"x":2.72,"y":3.53},
"NE":{"x":1.97,"y":8.83},
"SW":{"x":3.87,"y":4.83}}]
```

and the JavaScript function that handles the request is as follows:

```
send_json(res); //call function
function send_json(res)
{
  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(res);
  console.info(myJsonString);
  $.ajax({
  url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
  type: "GET", //request type
  contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  data: {data : myJsonString} ,
  success:function(result){
    //JSON version
    console.info(result);
    }
  });
}
```

The php file handles the request as follows:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  print_r($data);
}
?>
```

I've tried also to send the JSON as key value
JS:

```
data: {data: myJsonString}
```

and in turn received it in php via:

```
if(isset($_GET['data']))
{
echo json_decode($_GET['data']);
}
```

With no clue as well, the output is empty in both trials.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard all dependencies are included, and i have another function that instantiate another ajax call but with key-valued data, and it works fine

Comment: That still doesn't answer the questions. Have you *watched* the request / response?

Comment: from where can i watch them ? i can only see the error generated in the console tab

Comment: Look at the network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: i 've already did, there is no entries shown upon the request nor the response.

Comment: You see nothing being sent? Then you have other problems. How are you accessing the script which is supposed to make the AJAX request?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the script that make the ajax request is within a <script> tag in my html page. as i told you there is another ajax call that is working perfectly without any errors, the problem is caused by the way i pass the JSON array. btw; i've changed the data being sent to a simple string "hello" and it worked.

Comment: Check the stringify function to make sure it is doing what you expect. What does `myJsonStrng` look like? Can you post it here?

Comment: i did, i've printed it to the console. and the output is in my question var res= "......"

Comment: No, that is the object. Show us the result of `console.info(myJsonString);`

Comment: no that's actually the result of console.info(myJsonString) :
[{"id":-9007199254740990,
"NW":{"x":3.97,"y":5.83},
"SE":{"x":2.72,"y":3.53},
"NE":{"x":1.97,"y":8.83},
"SW":{"x":3.87,"y":4.83}}]

Comment: OK - the JSON is valid and you should see that being sent to the PHP script. If you put `print_r($_GET);` at the top of the PHP, what is the result?

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks man, the problem is solved, it couldn't be sent to using POST, but using get, it worked.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Both GET and POST are capable of sending a string.

Comment: I don't have any clue :S

Answer (score 1):

```
var res= [{"id":-9007199254740990,
"NW":{"x":3.97,"y":5.83},
"SE":{"x":2.72,"y":3.53},
"NE":{"x":1.97,"y":8.83},
"SW":{"x":3.87,"y":4.83}]
```

This is an array of json object, not a string
You can pass a json `object` as it is

```
data:res,
type: "post",
```

Now in server do

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Comment: i know that it not a string, it's just a name for the array :S I did so, and the outout was an empty array()

Comment: The OP converts to a string here `var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(res);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard this is the way i know to encode an array to JSON, do you have any other  ?

Comment: No, this is the correct way to convert to a string @JafarAlali92. I was just pointing out to Ima that you had done the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use GET if you are trying to send data to the server, use post instead

```
type: "post",
```

Comment: With jQuery AJAX you can send data via a GET request. It looks strange, but it works.

Comment: You can use a hammer to open a door too, but it's not the purpose of the GET method